# Why does it give an error when releasing the IPA application in Codemagic?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, codemagic

I want to get the IPA release, it gives this error

> Failed to install dependencies for pubspec file in
> /Users/builder/clone. Directory was not found

I uploaded my files into Gitlab and registered in Codemagic through Gitlab. I made all the relevant settings and entered the app store developer account. but it gives an error when I get the output.

Answer (score 0):

In your application settings, under `Build` > `Project path`, by default it is set to `.`. Click `Rescan` and then select the correct path to run the build in (for me, it was my flutter package).

See https://github.com/codemagic-ci-cd/codemagic-docs/discussions/1193